# Query winston log returns empty result

Tags: node.js, express, winston

I have a very basic express app. I added [**winston**](https://github.com/flatiron/winston#querying-logs) without any configuration. I create log messages like this:

```
require('winston').info('App started');
```

and all log messages go into `app.out.log`. When I `vi` into the file I see

```
info: App started
```

so default logging using winston seems to work fine. Now I want to use the query api of winston:

```
require('winston').query({}, function(err, results) {
    if (err) {
        res.status(400).json(err);
    } else {
        res.json(results);
    }
});
```

But results is empty. The doc says:

> Winston supports querying of logs with Loggly-like options. See Loggly
>   Search API. Specifically: File, Couchdb, Redis, Loggly, Nssocket, and
>   Http.

and since the default transport is File I would expect results to be not empty. Any ideas whats wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, Winston uses only ConsoleTransport. So if you want to query a log file, you have to add proper Transport (in this example is used file transport).

There is a little example:

```
var winston = require('winston');

winston.add(winston.transports.File, { filename: 'app.out.log' });

winston.info('App started');

winston.query({}, function(err, results) {
    if (err) {
      res.status(400).json(err);
  } else {
      res.json(results);
  }
});
```